# how to check if the space key is pressed once? unity 3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a plane controller by following a tutorial but I want it to check if the space key is pressed once, then run the if statement forever. I'm kinda new to unity and c# so if u want to, please explain your answer, thanks! :D

here is my plane controller script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement1 : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool throttle => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);

public float pitchPower, rollPower, yawPower, enginePower;

private float activeRoll, activePitch, activeYaw;

private void Update()
{
    if (throttle)
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * enginePower * Time.deltaTime;

        activePitch = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * pitchPower * Time.deltaTime;
        activeRoll = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * rollPower * Time.deltaTime;
        activeYaw = Input.GetAxisRaw("Yaw") * yawPower * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Rotate(activePitch * pitchPower * Time.deltaTime,
            activeYaw * yawPower * Time.deltaTime,
            -activeRoll * rollPower * Time.deltaTime,
            Space.Self); 
    }
    else
    {
        activePitch = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * (pitchPower / 2) * Time.deltaTime;
        activeRoll = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * (rollPower / 2) * Time.deltaTime;
        activeYaw = Input.GetAxisRaw("Yaw") * (yawPower / 2) * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Rotate(activePitch * pitchPower * Time.deltaTime,
            activeYaw * yawPower * Time.deltaTime,
            -activeRoll * rollPower * Time.deltaTime,
            Space.Self);
    }
}
}
```

thanks again for taking time and reading this!

Comment: i mean if u press space once, the if statement runs forever. and if u press it again, it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have a switch instead of a continous press like e.g.

```
// Store the actual value in a field
private bool _throttle;

// Too keep the public read-only access
public bool throttle => _throttle;

private void Update ()
{
    // Instead of checking for a continous press
    // this is only true in the one frame the key goes down
    // and simply inverts the value of _throttle
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) _throttle = !_throttle;

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for responding! but can you please explain your answer?

Comment: @KingPerfet_ I added some comments? Any doubts or questions?

Comment: nope, not at all thanks for taking time :)

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue here is that the throttle bool is assigned only once when the script is initialized. If you want to keep it similar you could turn it into a property instead.

```
public bool throttle
{
    get { return Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); }
}
```

If you plan on calling throttle in a bunch of place though I'd suggest to simply : throttle = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); at the beginning of the update loop.

Comment: `public bool throttle => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);` is exactly the same as `public bool throttle {  get { return Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); } }` or `public bool throttle
{ get => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); }` .. these are just different ways of writing it ;)